# Mining Bitcoin with scrypt, what will happen.. i

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-pools, mining-reward, cgminer, scrypt

What will happen if we mine bitcoin with scrypt algorithm... I tried with it by connecting to a bitcoin pool, with cgminer and it shows new block detected messages..

And what will happen if,  I mine it with bitcoin core...
In any case will it ever succeed..if it succeed.. is it bad for bitcoin core.. as the block generated by different algorithm..

Comment: Scrypt miners just like Sha256 miners are predominantly computed by ASIC meaning Application Specific Integrated Circuit. It is presumable that any coin that uses ASICs to mine will only allow miners that use the same algorithm to produce blocks. Dogecoin and Litecoin use the Scrypt algorithm and probably some other coins do as well. You could mine those coins interchangeably with a Scrypt ASIC but you can only mine bitcoin (or any other coin using sha256) with a Sha256 ASIC. However I wouldn't waste your sha256 ASIC  on something other than Bitcoin.

Answer (score 3):

Bitcoin Core uses SHA-256d as its proof-of-work function. If you use a different hashing algorithm such as Scrypt, your work output cannot produce a valid block for the Bitcoin blockchain—you are only converting energy to heat.